# C++ concepts placeholder type deduction

Tags: c++, c++-concepts

In the Ranges spec [N4622](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/n4622.pdf) the `Same` concept is defined to take two types `T` and `U`, but is sometimes used inside `requires` with just one like:

```
{ t } -> Same<T>;
```

What's the rule that enables the deduction for the 2nd type `U`? (e.g. from the Concepts spec [N4630](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/n4630.pdf))

The simplest similar example would be:

```
template <class T, class U>
concept bool C = (sizeof(T) == sizeof(U)) && (sizeof(U) != 1);

template <class T>
concept bool D = requires(T t){
  // How is U deduced here? 
  {t} -> C<T>; 
};

template <class T>
  requires D<T>
void fn() {}

int main() {
  // Fails with: unable to deduce placeholder type 'C<char>' from 't'
  // That's expected.
  //fn<char>();

  // But how does this work?
  fn<int>();
}
```

Tested sample using g++ 8.0.0 and -fconcepts.

Comment: Mentioning the commit hash or something might be wiser, as there is no official GCC 8 release (even GCC 7 is not out yet!).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## What's a placeholder?

A quick recap to make sure we’re all on the same page: a placeholder type is almost, but not quite a type. It’s a stand-in for a type that will be effectively be deduced. (Similarly there also are placeholder non-types [resp. templates] which are stand-ins for non-types. To avoid going on a tangent I’ll just mention their existence here and use the all-encompassing *placeholder* term from now on.)

Before concepts the only placeholders we have are the `auto` and `decltype(auto)` specifiers:

```
// the specifiers are all placeholders for `int`
auto i = 42;
auto& lref = i;
auto&& rref = 0;
decltype(auto) = 2 * i;
```

With concepts we can use placeholders in more intricate ways:

```
// two placeholders for `int`
std::pair<auto, auto> p = std::make_pair(1, 4);

// one placeholder
std::pair<auto, int> q = p;
```

And here’s where it gets tricky: a concept itself can be used as a placeholder:

```
template<typename Int>
concept bool Integral = …;

// placeholder for `int` constrained by `Integral<int>`
Integral a = 0;

// same as above
Integral<> b = a;

template<typename Lhs, typename Rhs>
concept bool EqualityComparable = …;

// another placeholder for `int`
// this time constrained by `EqualityComparable<int, double>`
EqualityComparable<double> c = a;
```

Read the binary `EqualityComparable` example carefully. What makes concepts as placeholders tricky is that the very first concept parameter has special treatment and will *not* be mentioned in the argument list. Whatever arguments appear in the angle bracket list (if any) correspond to the subsequent parameters.

## Placeholders in requirements

Let’s write a concept for something that has a `size()`. For the sake of demonstration we’ll be expecting that the result of this `size()` operation should be usable as an `Incrementable` variable (rather than something sensible like an `Integral` concept).

```
template<typename Incr>
concept bool Incrementable = requires(Incr incr) {
    ++incr;
};

template<typename Cont>
concept bool Sizeable = requires(Cont const cont) {
    // requirement #1
    { cont.size() } -> Incrementable
};
```

Our requirement #1 is a *compound requirement* of a special kind. Namely, it is one where a placeholder appears in the syntactic *trailing-return-type*. The effects are as if we had written:

```
template<Incrementable Incr>
void valid_for_incrementable(Incr incr);

template<typename Cont>
concept bool Sizeable = requires(Cont const cont) {
    cont.size();
    valid_for_incrementable(cont.size());
};
```

Plainly put the purpose of a compound requirement is to introduce two constraints at once: that the expression in brackets is valid, and that it can be used as the argument to an invented constraint-validating function template.

## All together now

Armed with our knowledge of placeholders and of their uses in compound requirements, we can find our answer:

```
template<typename T>
concept bool Demo = requires(T t) {
    { t } -> C<T>;
};
```

effectively means that we introduce a `C<T, T>` constraint on the `t` expression. Had the placeholder been `C<int>` instead, then the constraint would have been `C<T, int>` instead and so on.

Comment: Looks like the right answer. Let me go through the specs and digest it :)