# Unable to deduce placeholder type in concept

Tags: c++, c++-concepts, c++20

I'm trying to replicate standard C++20 concepts using Concepts TS in GCC 8 so I can use them before they are available in standard library. I mostly copy pasted everything from the latest draft and I came across a problem:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

// [concept.same]
template <typename T, typename U>
concept bool Same = std::is_same_v<T, U>;

// [concept.assignable]

// TODO: Proper implementation requires std::common_reference that is not in
// libstdc++ yet and implementing it myself is too hard.
template <typename LHS, typename RHS>
concept bool Assignable = std::is_lvalue_reference_v<LHS> &&
    requires(LHS lhs, RHS&& rhs)
    {
        {lhs = std::forward<RHS>(rhs)} -> Same<LHS>;
    };

template <typename T>
    requires Assignable<T&, T>
void Test(T a) {}

int main()
{
    Test(42);
}
```

A lot of other concepts require assignable types and when trying to use this concept I get:

```
Concepts.h:54:14: note: within 'template<class LHS, class RHS> concept const bool ftz::General::Assignable<LHS, RHS> [with LHS = int&; RHS = int]'
 concept bool Assignable = std::is_lvalue_reference_v<LHS> &&
              ^~~~~~~~~~
Concepts.h:54:14: note:     with 'int& lhs'
Concepts.h:54:14: note:     with 'int&& rhs'
Concepts.h:54:14: note: unable to deduce placeholder type 'ftz::General::Same<int&>' from 'lhs =(forward<int>)(rhs)'
```

What is the problem here?

Comment: Doesn't `Same` require two parameters?

Comment: @Frank There is a bit of [magic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43693697/c-concepts-placeholder-type-deduction) involved.

Comment: Why do you need `Same` for your code? Without that it works just fine: https://godbolt.org/z/XLQv8g -- but I'm probably missing the point of the question.

Comment: @chtz Because [that's how it is defined in the standard](http://eel.is/c++draft/concept.assignable).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a recent change made to Concepts that was adopted in the San Diego (November 2018) as a result of [P1084](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p1084r2.pdf). The problem is that it used to be that:

```
{ E } -> Same<T>;
```

Actually meant that the expression `f(E)` is valid for an invented function template of the form:

```
template <class U> requires Same<U, T> void f(U );
```

Which is obviously never going to hold for reference types `T` (as in the OP).

In other words, the old rule was that: `{ E } -> Same<T>` meant `Same<remove_cvref_t<decltype((E))>, T>`. The new rule is that it means `Same<decltype((E)), T>`. It appears that neither gcc's `-fconcepts` nor clang's concepts branch implements these new rules yet.

---

A current workaround is to change:

```
{ E } -> Same<LHS> // i.e. Same<T&>
```

to:

```
{ E } -> Same<std::remove_reference_t<LHS>>& // i.e. Same<T>&
```

Comment: Note that this works in current GCC trunk. GCC 9.3 and Clang trunk still don't have this implemented: https://godbolt.org/z/YbjCNB